# iOS SpriteKit creating and displaying objects from another class

Tags: ios, class, sprite-kit, addchild

I'm new to SpriteKit and I'm trying to display an object (a circle) created in a class, from MyScene.m. This is what I have:

in CreateNewCircle.h I wrote:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface CreateNewCircle : SKScene

-(void) addNewCircle;

@end
```

and in the .m (CreateNewCircle.m):

```
#import "CreateNewCircle.h"

@implementation CreateNewCircle

-(void) addNewCircle {

    const CGSize size = self.frame.size;

    const CGPoint center = CGPointMake(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.5);

    CGRect box = CGRectMake(center.x - 40.0, center.y - 40.0, 80.0, 80.0);

    SKShapeNode *shapeNode = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
    shapeNode.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:box].CGPath;
    shapeNode.fillColor = [SKColor redColor];
    shapeNode.strokeColor = nil;
}

@end
```

Now I'm trying to call this method (that display a circle onscreen) form MyScene.m:

MyScene.h:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface MyScene : SKScene

@end
```

MyScene.m:

```
#import "MyScene.h"
#import "CreateNewCircle.h"

@implementation MyScene {

}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithWhite:255 alpha:1.0];

        CreateNewCircle *circle1 = [[CreateNewCircle alloc] init];
        [circle1 addNewCircle];

        [self.scene addChild:circle1];

    }
    return self;
}
```

The build is OK, but when I run, nothing appear. I tried to change the "addchild" line such as:

```
[circle1 setName:@"circleOne"];

[self childNodeWithName:@"circleOne"];
```

but same result: blank screen. If I write the same code directly in MyScene.m, the circle appear, so the code should be correct. Can please someone help me :-) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example so you can make the changes you need to your code:

**MyScene.h**

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface MyScene : SKScene

@end
```

**MyScene.m**

```
#import "MyScene.h"
#import "CreateNewSprite.h"

@implementation MyScene
{
    //
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        CreateNewSprite *mySprite = [[CreateNewSprite alloc] init];
        [self addChild:mySprite];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    //
}

@end
```

**CreateNewSprite.h**

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface CreateNewSprite : SKShapeNode

@end
```

**CreateNewSprite.m**

```
#import "CreateNewSprite.h"

@implementation CreateNewSprite

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        SKShapeNode *shape = [SKShapeNode node];
        shape.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20) cornerRadius:4].CGPath;
        shape.position = CGPointMake(100,100);
        shape.strokeColor = [SKColor redColor];

        [self addChild:shape];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: It might be nice to explain the problem the OP is having, rather than just dumping a lot of code.

Comment: @JesseRusak - Then feel free to explain it to him. I have always preferred to learn by example.

Comment: OK, I tried some changes but still doesn't work.
Now I have the class like in the example:

`- (instancetype)init {`
`if (self = [super init]) {`
`................`

and I changed the subclass of my CreateNewCircle class to SKSpriteNode.

Comment: @user3457502 - Sorry about that. I forgot that SKShapeNode does not have an init method. The updated code shows you how to subclass SKShapeNode.